# How to display all age breakdown in boxplot

Tags: python, boxplot

```
list_of_gender = []

genderage = df.groupby('Gender')['Age'].count()
gender = genderage.index

for i in gender:
    temp = df[df["Gender"]==i]
    temp = temp.groupby('Age')['Gender'].count().tolist()
    list_of_gender.append(temp)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10')

plt.boxplot(list_of_gender, labels = gender)

plt.title('Planned Usage by Model', fontsize = 20)
plt.xlabel('Model', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Usage', fontsize = 15)

plt.show()
```

I can't seem to get all the age category in my boxplot. What can I do to get the boxplot that I have plotted in Tableau?

Please ignore the labels, I have not changed it to reflect the correct information.

[Wrong box plot - in Python](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iiQQUl7wN9T1rl-fjjibAl-Mb5S3R2hg/view?usp=sharing)

[Correct box plot - in Tableau](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n405hh30gpFypD5XocnfRot8SBtayRA9/view?usp=sharing)